# Is the Stack Exchange team using Trello?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Just wondering if they are and if it is public like the Trello development team's board is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The developers on the core engine are not.

The various community teams are, as well as the sysadmin team, and I believe the Careers dev team is as well.

None of these boards are public.