# What is "Trello Answers" and why is it scraping the SE sites?

Tags: discussion, robots, screen-scraping

Recently, I answered a question on Stack Overflow that is *very* specific to a certain platform. I tried [Googling the same question](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pipeline%20not%20found%20for%20current%20domain) to see who else was having this issue, and if the answer was available elsewhere. In searching, I came across this

"Trello Answers" post: http://trello.info/question/view/en/YUhSMGNEb3ZMM04wWVdOcmIzWmxjbVpzYjNjdVkyOXRMM0YxWlhOMGFXOXVjeTh6TkRNME56ZzFOUzlrWlcxaGJtUjNZWEpsTFhCcGNHVnNhVzVsTFc1dmRDMW1iM1Z1WkMxbWIzSXRZM1Z5Y21WdWRDMWtiMjFoYVc0PQ==

which appears to be a page scrape of a previous version of the question / answer from here:

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34347855/1790644)

I have no problem with crawlers that help expand visibility of certain issues, but on this "Trello Answers" page, there is *absolutely no reference to the original that they blatantly stole from*. Is there something to be done about this?

It seems as if they go as far as to clear the referrer to a link in the post `http://blankrefer.com/?https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb2VZ.png`

*edit*

In browsing this scrapers page, it would seem as if 100% of their content has come from SE with not a single attribution. I will be contacting SE moderators to see what can be done.

Cheers

Comment: Huzzah, sorry for the duplicate, this answers perfectly. I'll see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: lol, don't worry about it. Duplicates are a good thing :)

Comment: For what it's worth, there is a legitimate product called [Trello](https://trello.com/) that [some SE employees use](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109712/is-the-stack-exchange-team-using-trello). The SCRAPER you have found appears to me to have about as much authorization to use the Trello name as they do to claim ownership of content originally posted to Stack Exchange sites (which is to say, not at all).

Comment: Huh, interesting. I did come across the official _trello_ in my googling to see what was going on, and assumed they were related until both you said something, and I ran a whois query against the domain.

I have filed a support request with SE. Thanks all, cheers, and Happy Holidays!

Comment: If they choose to act, it is up to them, but I also submitted a support ticket to _the real Trello_ for possible trademark infringement. We shall see what happens.